# gridview link cell and search option based on multiple text fields feature

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, desktop-application

I am trying to build a webform with gridview.

The feature of gridview are;

- load data from table
- edit link field in each row
- search data based on multiple fields on search button click and show data in the same grid

I tried to search in internet but can not found appropriate examples. All the examples are based on "`search as you type`" or `only single text box field search option`.

Suppose the table is;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user_information](
    [user_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [status] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [role] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [phone_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [mobile_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [local_address] [int] NULL,
    [permanent_address] [int] NULL,
    [email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [user_created_date] [date] NULL,
    [password_valid_days] [int] NULL,
    [password_changed_date] [date] NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_user_information] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [user_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Search fields are [user_name], [user_created_date] and [role]? Please help.

Comment: show us the necessary part of your aspx page and the code behind. And I recommend you to check on [this](https://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my problem is with `win forms i.e. desktop application` not `asp.net`.

Comment: then that must be much easier, you can just create a textbox for search and do like textbox change event. Let us know what have you tried.